# Странное поведение русских букв

Tags: php, get

Возьмем простейший скрипт, назовем его testget.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
$rowname = "мм";
$formid = 11;
echo "<a href=\"delete.php?zname=$rowname&formid=$formid\"> Удалить </a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

и запустим из некой папки:

http://www.example.com/sp/testget.php

Если выбрать ссылку, то скрипт "вылетает" по адресу http://www.example.com/

Если заменить $rowname на одну русскую букву м, то все работает нормально и выдается текст

Not Found
The requested URL /sp/delete.php was not found on this server.

Все, естественно, работает нормально, если $rowname содержит латинские символы и большинство русских букв, включая пробелы, например, "Вид програм". Но если добавить еще одну м "Вид программ" - все вылетает. Я в растерянности. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что это и как с этим бороться.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` включён? `RewriteRule` присутствует?

Comment: К сожалению, мне не разрешено на моем хостинге даже видеть httpd.conf. Я задал этот вопрос службе поддержки и жду от них решения проблемы и комментариев.

Comment: Я получил ответ из службы поддержки. Их модуль mod_security рассматривает некоторые комбинации русских букв как попытку взлома SQL (SQL injection). Там у них очень сложный regesp и если паттерн подходит, сервер перенаправляет запрос в корневую папку с кодом 302. После отключения mod_security  все работает нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с нелатинскими символами (да и вообще все что отлично от цифр) в строке URL лучше всего делать через [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

```
$rowname=urlencode($rowname);
```

А обратное преобразование собственно через [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: В общем это верно. Но в данном случае не помогает. urlencode() перекодирует 'мм' в %D0%BC%D0%BC , что происходит и так, без всякой urlencode(). Мне кажется, urlencode() полезна, когда в строке есть пробелы и другие нецифробуквенные символы.

Comment: Главное, это амперсанды(`&`) и равно(`=`), остальное не критично, браузеры нынче умные =)